# Oracle Java update screws up PATH variable

Tags: java

I have noticed that every time you update your java, good old Oracle decides to add the JRE installation to the front of your path variable.

This, for us java developers, screws everything up as we usually have our JDK set to our JAVA_HOME. We have noticed this happening since Java 8 at our office and it throws everyone off as echo $JAVA_HOME spits out the correct value but java -version does not.

We always remove the value Oracle puts on the front of the PATH variable and replace it with %JAVA_HOME%\bin.

My question is, is there a way to disable this behaviour from the JRE updates that you install when prompted while surfing the web from legitimate sources?

How does this screw us up? Take JBoss 7 for instance, it will not start under JDK 8 (you need WildFly), so when you change our java version from JDK 7 to JRE 8, you break us.

Comment: Simple solution: disable the installation of the "public JRE" when you install the JDK.

Comment: To add to what @a_horse_with_no_name says, there are many ways to keep a _development_ environment stable. This should be separate from how you _deploy_, say, a JBoss app. It is unclear from your question which one of these environments you are primarily interested in (or both); there are different techniques for either.

Comment: I'd say your local deploy environment should be independent of your operating system. Have you considered using virtual environment for that purpose, say using [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) or similar?

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys, I am talking specifically about development environments. Our test & production servers do not have this problem as they are linux based and reference the JAVA_HOME. 

I guess the solution for JBoss is to force our local one to use JAVA_HOME as well and not just java.